# Отобразить контент jquery

Tags: html, jquery

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Изначально отображается всё. 
По нажатию на определенную категорию отображаются нужные нам товары. Нужен наиболее оптимальный способ

Comment: Задать атрибут категории каждому элементу, и в зависимости от нажатого элемента скрывать все кроме элементов с указанной категорией?

Comment: @nickita-davidenko Да, именно так

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый простой способ:

```js
var category = function(cat) {

  $('[data-category]').each(function() {
    var _cat = String( $(this).data('category') );
    
    if( cat === 'null' || cat === _cat){
      $(this).removeClass('hide');
    }else if( cat !== _cat ){
      $(this).addClass('hide');
    };
  });
};

$('a').click(function() {
  var cat = $(this).attr('href');
  
  category( cat );
  
  return false;
});
```

```css
.hide {opacity: 0.4}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <a href="null">Все</a>
  <a href="0">Категория 0</a>
  <a href="1">Категория 1</a>
  <a href="2">Категория 2</a>
</div>

<p data-category="0">Категория 0</p>
<p data-category="1">Категория 1</p>
<p data-category="1">Категория 1</p>
<p data-category="0">Категория 0</p>
<p data-category="2">Категория 2</p>
<p data-category="2">Категория 2</p>
<p data-category="0">Категория 0</p>
<p data-category="1">Категория 1</p>
<p data-category="0">Категория 0</p>
```